# How to create a static page where to add posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new with Wordpress and I need some help.
I have added this theme to my website ([theam demo link](https://colorlib.com/sparkling/)) and I am trying to create a page where I can add new post and every post must be on the same page and with a read more button (like home page from the link).

Comment: (*Not 100% accurate wording*) You need to set the setting in the theme customizer menu under "static front page" to *display latest posts"...well...something like that

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Reading and under "Front page displays" select "Your latest posts."

You should go to the WordPress site and read the getting started as this is a basic setting. Also, read the documentation that comes from the theme developer. It will have further information as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress admin,

go to Pages » Add New to create a new page Like Blog

go to Settings » Reading

under the Front page displays option choose A static page.

under the Blog page displays option choose A Blog page.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

You should create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) where you can enter a [custom template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) where you can enter the [custom loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) you need to have the posts you want to show.

Then you will need to create a page and activate it with the custom 
template you made.

Hope that can help, however there are a lot of other ways to achieve what you want and this one is not the most beginner friendly but i think it is the most developer friendly, so i think you should at least check it out.

Answer (score -2):

install the plugin visual composer it will help you a lot